# Reading text file into variable, subsequent print() returns escape characters?

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-16

Been searching around on this one to no avail.  I have a snippet where I want to read a text file into a variable in python so that I can refer to it later (specifically to kill a running process).

File is generated like this:

`os.system('wmic process where ^(CommandLine like "pythonw%pycpoint%")get ProcessID > windowsPID.txt')`

Resulting text file `windowsPID.txt` looks like this:

`ProcessId

4076`

My python snippet to read the file looks like this:

`with open('windowsPID.txt') as f:
    print "In BuildLaunch, my PID is: " 
    b = f.readlines()
    print b`

`print b` outputs the following:

`['\xff\xfeP\x00r\x00o\x00c\x00e\x00s\x00s\x00I\x00d\x00 \x00 \x00\r\x00\n', '\x004\x000\x007\x006\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00\r\x00\n', '\x00']`

I can see the 4076, but why can't I get it to output properly?  I just need that second line.

**UPDATE**

**As mentioned by roippi, this can be fixed by forcing the file to open in unicode-16:**

`import codecs
    with codecs.open('windowsPID.txt', encoding='utf-16') as f:`

All fixed!

-Chow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python by default tries to open files using utf-8 encoding, but your file is otherwise encoded, so you get raw bytes output to your screen.

`\xff\xfe` is the UTF-16 (LE) [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).  You need to open your file with the proper encoding.

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('windowsPID.txt', encoding='utf-16') as f:
```

Comment: Started with an error, but did a quick search once you gave me something to look for -- edited answer above.